# Turn on GZip for Laravel Ajax calls

Tags: ajax, apache, .htaccess, laravel, gzip

I have a 2 views that make several ajax calls to some controllers. They return JSON results.

Google PageSpeed claimed I should enable it to achieve 89% compression (my page contacts the server every second, to update status).

I've enabled gzip through the .htaccess at the root the /public subdirectory - meaning all my static resources get compressed. But all my Ajax results do not. Where do I enable it? Do I add another .htaccess somewhere, or enable it in the PHP code itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved: the .htaccess in the public directory is enough, since everything is served off the index.php page. All I was missing was `application/json` at the DEFLATE line.

Answer (score 8):

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/json
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
</IfModule>
```

This is what I use